# Explanation on a proof of a lemma on the Adams-Bashforth method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

> Lemma: For the two-step Adams-Bashforth (AB) method $$T(t)=\frac{5}{12} y'''(t)h^2+\mathcal{O}(h^3),$$ where $T(t)$ denotes the local truncation error.

By definition, $$T(t)=\frac{y(t+h)-y(t)}{h}-f(t,y(t)).$$
For the AB method, $$T(t)=\frac{y(t+h)-y(t)}{h}-\sum_{j=0}^{r}b_jf(t-jh,y(t-jh)).$$
The lemma is the result for $r=1$.  By Taylor's theorem,
\begin{align}
\frac{y(t+h)-y(t)}{h}&=\frac{\left(y(t)+y'(t)h+y''(t)h^2/2+y'''(t)h^3/6+\mathcal{O}(h^4)\right)-y(t)}{h} \tag{1}\\
&=y'(t)+\frac{y''(t)}{2}h+\frac{y'''(t)}{6}h^2+\mathcal{O}(h^3) \tag{*}
\end{align}For $r=1$: 
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{1}b_jf(t-jh,y(t-jh))&=b_0f(t,y(t))+b_1f(t-h,y(t-h)) \\
&=\frac{3}{2}f(t,y(t))-\frac{1}{2}f(t-h,y(t-h))  \ \ \ (b_0=3/2, \ b_1=-1/2)\\
&=\frac{3}{2}y'(t)-\frac{1}{2}y'(t-h) \ \ \ (y'(t)=f(t,y(t)) ) \\
&=\frac{3}{2}y'(t)-\frac{1}{2}\left(y'(t)-y''(t)h+\frac{1}{2}y'''(t)h^2+\mathcal{O}(h^3)\right) \tag{2} \\
&=y'(t)+\frac{y''(t)}{2}h-\frac{y'''(t)}{4}h^2+\mathcal{O}(h^3) \tag{**}
\end{align}
Now the result follows by subtracting $(**)$ from $(*)$, but I don't understand how Taylor's theorem was used in steps $(1)$ and $(2)$, i.e. the expansions of $y(t+h)$ and $y'(t-h)$.

Comment: These steps look like perfectly fine applications of the Taylor expansion. Perhaps you could add to the question what you think is Taylor's theorem and where you see a difference in the mentioned steps?

Comment: Your formula for the truncation error is wrong, it only applies to the Euler method. It should be $$T(h)=\frac1h\sum a_ky(t-kh)-\sum b_kf(t-kh,y(t-kh))$$ for the general multi-step method.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I don't understand where the $h$ comes from in the Taylor expansion. Also, the truncation error has been taken directly from my textbook. I will need to check if this is an error.

Comment: So your problem is not with the expansions of $y(x+h) and $y'(x-h)$, but why these terms occur in the formula?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm just a bit rusty atm. Are the following correct?
\begin{align}
y(t+h)&=y(t)+y'(t)(t+h-t)+y''(t)(t+h-t)^2+\mathcal{O}(h^3) \\
&=y(t)+y'(t)h+y''(t)h^2 +\mathcal{O}(h^3)
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
y'(t-h)&=y'(t)+y''(t)(t-h-t)+y'''(t)(t-h-t)^2+\mathcal{O}(h^3) \\
&=y'(t)-y''(t)h+y'''(t)h^2+\mathcal{O}(h^3)
\end{align}

Comment: Nearly correct, you need to divide by the factorials, $$f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2!}f''(x)+\frac{h^3}{3!}f'''(x)+O(h^4).$$

Comment: @LutzLehmann Of course! Maybe this is a sign that I should go to bed.